# How to change the size of an image and download it with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to download the same image with different height and width according to parameters of the function. Here is my code :

```
function Download(name, QRsrc, height, width) {

if (name.length > 20) {
    name = name.substring(0, 20);
}
var a = $("<a>")
    .attr("href", QRsrc)
    .height(height)
    .width(width)
    .attr("download", name)

    .appendTo("body");

a[0].click();

a.remove();

}
```

And I am calling this function like this

```
Download('@survey.Name.Replace(" ","_")','@QRsrc','200','200')
```

But it does not work . The size of the downloaded image does not change with parameters. How can I solve this problem. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need write the resize image method on the server.
2. Call your remote method

Maybe you can try the [picture tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture), currently few browser support this

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried so many times to handle it in client but it did not work. Now I did it on server and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Client side solution:

that height and width attributes are just css rules, they don't change the original image size.... you can use a new canvas based on the original image.

```
function downloadCanvas(link, canvasId, filename) {
    link.href = document.getElementById(canvasId).toDataURL();
    link.download = filename;
}
```

- Create a canvas using this [tutorial](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/how-to-develop-a-html5-image-uploader/)
- [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/7PRNN/) an easy way to download your canvas by using the function above:

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Image resize can be possible using canvas(client side), I have created following code for resizing the Image.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var resizeImage = function(src,width,height) {
 var orig_src = new Image(),
 resize_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
 orig_src.src = src;
 resize_canvas.width = width;
 resize_canvas.height = height;
 resize_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(orig_src, 0, 0, width, height);
 $(".resize-image").attr('src', resize_canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
}
$(function(){
 resizeImage('image.jpg',100,100); // Image path, width, height
});
</script>
<img class="resize-image" src="image.jpg" />
```